# Is Portal 2 Talent Show Achievement disabled?

Tags: pc, achievements, portal-2

I and my friend just completed [that chamber](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtJeZMb5TYM) and we did not lose any cube and we didn't get the Talent Show achievement.

We repeated the chamber, not losing the cube again and we still didn't receive the achievement...

Therefore, is the Talent Show achievement disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the Sixense MotionPack? If so, that might be your problem.

Fix:

> It is possible to disable the motionpack by adding the launch option "-nosixense" in Steam. (right click on Portal 2 in the games list, select Properties, then Set Launch Options...)

**EDIT:** Valve released [a patch](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6490/) on October 11, 2011 which solves this issue. Change log of that patch:

> - Fixed the Talent Show achievement not being awarded properly

Answer (score 0):

Is either of you on a PS3 or Xbox 360? If so, you won't be able to get the achievement. That achievement was added to Portal 2 as part of the Steam Summer Sale promotion and was only available for the desktop version of Steam.

References:

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1985962

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1981949.html

(I know this from personal experience as well.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It's on PC, I used the PC tag...

Comment: Yes, but you might have been on PC while your friend was on a console; you might not even have known it.

Comment: Interesting, that makes sense!